# G-sense errors in new disks

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-raid, synology, smart, seagate

I have a Synology DiskStation. It used to contain 3xTB drives, I now have 2xTB, 2x8TB drives. The old drives were "Seagate NAS" drives, the new ones are from the same(?) series, named "Ironwolf".

The old drives both list G_Sense_Error_Rate at 0. The new ones are now at ~800 and slowly climbing.

Why would they differ (in the same enclosure)? Is there something I can do to stop it from increasing?

Answer (score 0):

The G_Sense_Error_Rate is about vibrations that the drive experiences, you may want to see if the enclosure can be moved to a less noisy area or padded somehow to reduce the rate. It may also be that the new drives are not a good match for the hardware that you have and that the fans have vibrations that are at an harmonic frequency to the drive sensitivity.